# Angular-redactor: How to setup blur callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea, onblur, redactor

**THE SITUATION:**

I am using [angular-redactor](https://github.com/TylerGarlick/angular-redactor) as editor for my app.

Everything is working fine except just one thing.
I need to fire a blur event to ask confirmation to the user in case he want to leave the page without saving.

**THE CODE**

This is the redactor textarea:

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="30" ng-model="body" ng-blur="confirmation_email_exit()"redactor="
    { 
      minHeight: 370,
      focus: true,
      plugins: ['fontcolor', 'table', 'fullscreen', 'counter', 'fontfamily'],

    }">
</textarea>
```

This is an example of global options properly working:

```
app.config(function(redactorOptions) {

    redactorOptions.buttons = ['formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic'];

});
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i fire a blur event with angular-redactor?

I have to call it in the view or setup as a global option?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Redactor's blurCallback, and you can use it both in view and in redactorOptions:

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="30" ng-model="body" redactor="
    { 
      minHeight: 370,
      focus: true,
      plugins: ['fontcolor', 'table', 'fullscreen', 'counter', 'fontfamily'],
      blurCallback: function(){confirmation_email_exit()},
    }">
</textarea>
```

or

```
app.config(function(redactorOptions) {

   redactorOptions.buttons = ['formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic'];
   redactorOptions.blurCallback = function(){confirmation_email_exit()};

});
```